# What are my options for integrating audacity into shell scripts?

Tags: scripting, software-rec

Just generally, I mean. Ideally I want to be able to script the nyquist plugins directly from the Linux command line by means of one-liners. A cursory glance at scripting audacity shows that it's possible to use a command interpreter from within audacity, but as far as being able to use that interpreter or script the program itself, I wasn't able to come up with any info. What are my options for manipulating audio from the command line with audacity? Is it a bunch of hassle, or doable in one-liners? If it's not possible to write a one-liner, maybe it's better to use a Python library instead, or some other program... (recommendations encouraged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't script Audacity](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=7220) but [pure Nyquist](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rbd/doc/nyquist/index.html) should do the trick, (unless you're allergic to parentheses (it is lisp after all))...

In which case, you probably wish you could [do something like this](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27801744). It's not Audacity (you can't apt-get these features), but it's not not Audacity (you need to tweak the Audacity source code...). And then there's the fact that it [fails to produce audio in some cases](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=57129).

Using Python has never seemed like such a good idea..